# construct condition in save model in django admin

Tags: python, django

I have Contact model and I want to construct it to have only 1 record with field is_active=True.
but I don't want to raise error, I want it to notify me and don't save the record if there is an contact record with is_active=True before in admin site.
"Contact can't have more than 1 active contact at same time."

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_active:
            if Contact.objects.filter(Q(is_active=True), ~Q(id=self.id)):
            // raise ValidationError("Contact can't have more than 1 active contact at same time.")
        return super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What do you mean with "notify me, but not raise an error"?

Comment: I want to appear pop or message not validation error

Comment: well that is front-end. If you call the validation, and the form is not valid, then you can use Django's Message framework, or JavaScript to display a message (after an AJAX call). But normally the validation is done in the `def clean` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will want to use a [Django Signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/signals/) hook to intercept the saving of a contact. That's the best way to make sure that faulty data isn't inserted, whether from the admin site or elsewhere. To ensure it doesn't happen, however, you will need to raise an exception.

To make the admin site show an appropriate error to the user, however, you'll need to override the form on the controller. For example:

```py
class ContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact

        def clean(self):
            ... do your validation here, raising forms.ValidationError as needed ...
            return self.cleaned_data


class ContactAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ContactForm
```

Answer (score 0):

In the custom `save` function, simply instead of throwing an error, you return it without executing the request:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.is_active:
            if Contact.objects.filter(Q(is_active=True), ~Q(id=self.id)):
                return
        return super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: it saves the record, but I don't want to save it if another record has is_active=True

Comment: I want to notify the user with the issue by using EX: popup. (in admin)